# MongoDB- How to remove duplicate documents?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I am trying to create a script to remove duplicates from a collection using the MongoDB aggregation framework.

**Input:**
some of the documents in the collection

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6122ca5df5ee9d5974c6e886"},"Name":"ccc","cusId":1}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6122ca5df5ee9d5974c6e887"},"Name":"ddd","cusId":4}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6122ca5df5ee9d5974c6e888"},"Name":"eee","cusId":5}
{"_id":{"$oid":"612bc88610921de4b5a6bd0d"},"Name":"last","cusId":1}
{"_id":{"$oid":"61571141c8cdee23c9a46a3a"},"Name":"lastRecord","cusId":1}
```

**Script to find duplicates except the last inserted document**

```
$group
{ 
     _id:  "$cusId", 
             
            mongoIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
            count: { $sum: 1 } 
 },$match
{
  count: { $gt: 1 }
},$project
{
   
   "duplicates":{
      "$filter":{
         "input":"$mongoIds",
         "as":"mongoId",
         "cond":{
            "$lt":[
               "$$mongoId",
               {
                  "$max":"$mongoIds"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**the expected results**

the expected output of the script is the array duplicates to contain only documents that are duplicated except the **last inserted** document to the array.

for instance, for documents with cusId 4 and 5, there are no duplicates for this cusId so they should not be included in the duplicates array. but for documents with cusId 1, there should be 2 duplicates (all documents with cusId 1 except the last inserted document)

so the final result should be all duplicates except the last inserted document

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6122ca5df5ee9d5974c6e886"},"Name":"ccc","cusId":1}
{"_id":{"$oid":"612bc88610921de4b5a6bd0d"},"Name":"last","cusId":1}
```

**how to remove duplicates where cusId is the same and keep only the latest inserted document in the collection? How can I get document creation time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$lookup` self collection with a subpipeline
2. In the subpipeline, do a `$group` to get the latest timestamp through `$toDate : "$_id"`
3. filter the root document by `$ne` to the timestamp of the `$lookup` result (i.e. not the latest document)
4. `$out` the result to another collection. You can then use this output collection to prune your original collection through a simple [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wvuk-eDXkmc) for your reference.

Comment: the data set I am working with does not have a created field(I updated my question to reflect that) the only way to get the creation day is to use the ObjectId (_id).getTimeStamp but I do not know how to get the creation day using the aggregation framework

Comment: You can simply use `$toDate` to extract timestamp from objectId. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the expected result should be the documents that are duplicated (i.e cusId 4 and 5  does not have duplicates should not show in the results but cusId 1 has duplicates so the result should have all the duplicates except the last inserted document to the collection

Comment: Can you update your question to put a concrete example of your expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question to include expected results

Comment: updated the answer accordingly